# SQL - Counting Distinct records based on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I know there has to be an easy way to do this, but I am drawing a blank. I am looking at 3 fields; CustomerID, Code, CodeDate

When a code goes on a customer ID, it gets a code date. I am looking for a count of codes by customer ID in a date range, but with distinct dates.

```
ID     Date       Code
ABC    1/2/17     XYZ
ABC    1/3/17     XYZ
ABC    1/4/17     XYZ
ABC    1/4/17     XYZ
ABC    1/5/17     XYZ
```

In this case there are 5 records, but i want the end results to show

```
ID      CodeCount
ABC     4
```

Since 1/4 is duplicated.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT Id AS [Type],
       COUNT(DISTINCT date) AS Count
FROM table
GROUP BY Id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Trunc() on the Date column within count(distinct) to consider the two dates to be same.Take a look at the output of this query.

```
      SELECT dt "Date" ,
         COUNT( DISTINCT dt2 ) OVER () c_dtime ,
         COUNT( DISTINCT TRUNC(dt2) ) OVER () c_date FROM
         ( SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) dt , SYSDATE dt2 FROM DUAL
      UNION ALL
         SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE + 0.04, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) dt ,
           SYSDATE + 0.04 dt2
      FROM DUAL
         ) ;
-------------------------------------------
      Date,         C_Dtime, C_Date
06/09/2017 22:47:54 2        1
06/09/2017 21:50:18 2        1
```